# How to get all the elements within a ng-form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-ng-form

Is it possible to get all the elements within a ng-form, as it is possible with form?

For:

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm">...</form>
```

This works:

```
document.forms["myForm"].elements
```

But for:

```
<ng-form name="myForm" id="myForm">...</ng-form>
```

Neither this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("ng-form")["myForm"].elements
```

nor this:

```
document.getElementById("myForm").elements
```

seem to work. They return undefined.

Is there a way with ng-form to get all its elements?

Comment: Do you really need all elements, or you want to access models of elements inside form?

Comment: I need to be able to do the following: angular.element("#" + elements[i].id).scope().innerForm.$valid, where the elements array is the one returned from the statements described above.

Comment: I am sure that you are not seeing this with a correct angular approach...

Answer (score 0):

This may work if a non-jQuery solution is desired:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("ng-form")[0].getElementsByTagName("*")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can select all sub items via Jquery.

```js
    var subItems = $('#myForm *');
```